# Angular POST request not executed

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a POST request that doesn't seem to execute.

```
private loginBackend(): Observable<Response> {
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlSearchParams.append('ticket', this.ticket.toString());
urlSearchParams.append('serviceURL', this.callbackURL);
this.loginEndPoint = (environment.backUri || window.location.origin) + environment.endpoints.login;
console.log("pass")
    return this.http
        .post(this.loginEndPoint, urlSearchParams, { withCredentials: true })
        .map((dt: any) => {
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.isLogIn();
        })
        .catch(this.catchResponseError);
}
```

I'm trying to set a variable to true if the ticket is validated by the backend.

This is the call to the method :

```
 if (this.ticket) {
        // We try to autenticate
        return this.loginBackend()
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use subscribe otherwise it wont get invoked

```
 if (this.ticket) {
        // We try to autenticate
        return this.loginBackend().subscribe(data=>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the http client from Angular, you get an observable as a return. This observable has a source. In your case, the source of data is your http call. This source is actually created only when you subscribe to your observable.

So basically, you need to subscribe to your observable to actually make your http post request :

```
 if (this.ticket) {
    // We try to authenticate
    return this.loginBackend().subscribe(data => {
        // Do your stuff with your response
    )
 }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!